# Stored procedure - Group By Id another value equals parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, view, procedure

This is for SQL Server 2012

I have the following results

```
GameId    |    TeamId    
------------------------
1              50
1              40
2              50
2              40
3              30
3              20
```

I want to pass in a `TeamId` into my stored procedure (`TeamId = 40`) and return results grouped by `GameId` where one of the `TeamId = 40`.

When I do this it just returns all the records that contain `TeamId = 40`. But I need to maintain the other record and return the following results.

```
GameId    |    TeamId    
------------------------
1              50
1              40
2              50
2              40
```

Thanks for any replies in advance.

Comment: The answer provided by @Dustin, works perfectly based on your requirements, by why would you need grouping?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: I updated to say its for SQL Server 2012.

Comment: I seem to have over complicated this in my head. My SQL knowledge is very limited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query from your result where TeamId = 40:

```
SELECT GameId, TeamId
FROM yourTable
WHERE GameId IN (SELECT GameId FROM yourTable WHERE TeamId = 40);
```

This should give you the same results you posted

Comment: Thanks very much Dustin. I seem to have over complicated this in my head. You solution works perfectly. Thank you.